# How to inherit generic types in implementations without having generic interfaces in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

I'm writing this SDK where I need to define functionality in publicly accessible interfaces as:

```
interface CommonEndPoint {
   fun doSomething(listener: IListener<CommonType>)
}
```

and then implement the common interface in the sub-project as:

```
interface SpecialEndpoint : CommonEndpoint {
  fun doSomething(listener: IListener<SpecialType>)
}
```

where SpecialType extends CommonType.

I have defined the contra-variant generic listener as:

```
interface IListener<in T> {
   receiveResult(result: T)
}
```

The problem is:

1. I need the SDK user to work with the SpecialType, not the CommonType
2. I need to override the method names as they are

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- I have tried generic functions, they didn't work either as they need to specify the type.
- I cannot use @JvmName because these methods are open/override
- At the moment I use abstract classes with protected/internal constructors to define the methods that need to be defined and implemented

**Why not generic interfaces?** The interfaces are not meant to be generics because the types are only used in one function, but the listeners should be generic as they are used everywhere in the project. Plus, the same implementation is supposed to be done for iOS with Objective-C compatibility, which means I have to support light-weight generics there and if I make the interfaces generic, I have to write my code three times for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to use generic common interfaces in this form:

```
interface CommonEndPoint<TYPE1 : CommonType> {
    fun doSomething(listener: IListener<TYPE1>)
}
```

And inherit in the specialised endpoint like this:

```
interface SpecialEndpoint : CommonEndpoint<SpecialType> {
    fun doSomething(listener: IListener<SpecialType>)
}
```

Which works perfectly for Java/Kotlin code. And drop Listeners and switch to closures for iOS/Objective-C which translates to blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need covariance instead of contravariance to get SpecialType to be used. The kotlin page is pretty helpful I think. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Actually I read that documentation and it didn't help with this case.
The issue is the methods cannot have the same signature.
Covariant types cannot be used here because they're specified by "out" keyword which means they can be the output of the method (return value), while the listener type is an input.

Comment: Then you have requirements to the interface that contradict the limitations you want to impose on the usage. Could you elaborate about the reason in is required?